# Confusion over PROCESSING ORDER of "distinct", "top" and "order by" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and SQL Server and is having trouble understanding the PROCESSING order of different clauses in a query.

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) name
FROM tblEmployees
ORDER BY birthday;
```

I understand that the actually processing order of the query is:

```
FROM 
SELECT 
ORDER BY
```

However, it seems to me that clauses such as `DISTINCT` and `TOP` is dependent on the result of the `ORDER BY` clause. So if the `SELECT` clause is executed before `ORDER BY` clause, how can `DISTINCT` and `TOP` uses the result from the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is logically processed in below order

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

`DISTINCT` processed before `ORDER BY` so `DISTINCT` is not dependent on `ORDER BY`.

First duplicates will be removed from result because of `DISTINCT` then `ORDER BY` will be applied

Comment: oh ok, i always thought "distinct" and "top" are part of "select" clause, thanks for clarify the concept!

Comment: and also, I just checked out your profile. It seems to me that you are a expert at sql/tsql, may I ask for some suggestions as to what is the best learning path for sql for a beginner like me? any wisdom and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @TonyStark - Thanks for the appreciation.. am not a expert and all.. Just ask your question here there are many people to help you

Comment: you are so modest :) anyway, thanks again for your help! much appreciate it!